# I need css code to divide my webpage sections into two columns

Tags: css, html

```
<main>
    <a href="blogslist.html">
        <h2 class="section-heading">All Blogs</h2>
    </a>

    <section>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-image">
                <a href="blogpost.html">
                    <img src="img/1.png" alt="Card Image">
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="card-description">
                <a href="blogpost.html">
                    <h3>The Blog Title Here</h3>
                </a>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis ipsa delectus maxime saepe dolorum odio, commodi tempora architecto eius ut repellat! Praesentium, officiis magnam sit tenetur expedita ullam sunt quibusdam.
                </p>
                <a href="blogpost.html" class="btn-readmore">Read more</a>
                <p></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-image">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="img/2.png" alt="Card Image">
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="card-description">
                <a href="#">
                    <h3>The Blog Title Here</h3>
                </a>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Dolorem veritatis molestias sequi necessitatibus natus. Tempore, recusandae repellendus alias libero suscipit dolore aperiam doloribus voluptatum necessitatibus quod soluta quo modi dolorum!
                </p>
                <a href="#" class="btn-readmore">Read more</a>
            </div>
        </div> 
        
    </section>

    <h2 class="section-heading">All Projects</h2>

    <section>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-image">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="img/3.png" alt="Card Image">
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="card-description">
                <a href="#">
                    <h3>The Projects Title Here</h3>
                </a>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Explicabo consequatur eveniet reiciendis, delectus unde debitis labore architecto voluptas qui et atque nulla obcaecati ratione maiores? Dolor dolores pariatur minus nam?
                </p>
                <a href="#" class="btn-readmore">Read more</a>
            </div>
            <p></p>
        </div>

        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-image">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="img/3.png" alt="Card Image">
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="card-description">
                <a href="#">
                    <h3>The Project Title Here</h3>
                </a>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor  sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos iusto culpa quaerat dolor iste! Dolores earum dolorum, explicabo mollitia illo autem porro quae, necessitatibus eius dolore, dolorem natus iusto veritatis!
                </p>
                <a href="#" class="btn-readmore">Read more</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    
</main>
```

Comment: Please add more explanation here so your question is reproducible and answerable.

Answer (score 0):

First, move your headings into their sections, so your structure looks more like this:

```
<main>
   <section>
      Heading Here
      Cards Here
   </section>
   <section>
      Heading Here
      Cards Here
   </section>
</main>
```

Then you can do this in a few different ways with CSS. The simplest way is to add a class to each section and then float the first one left with a right margin of 1%, float the second one to the right with a left margin of 1%, and give them a width of 48% each. This will ensure they are 2 columns at all times.

If you're using more modern techniques, have an autoprefixer installed (or are familiar with writing compatibility for css), and are looking for a responsive solution, I would use flexbox. Here's how I would do this in SCSS.

```
.main {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-left: -15px;
    margin-right: -15px;

    @media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
    }

    section {
        width: calc(100% - 30px);
        margin: 15px;

        @media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
        width: calc(100% / 2 - 30px);
        }
    }
}
```